# How to interleave items from 2 lists backward

Tags: python

Word Problem:

Create a function to interleave the letters of two strings (starting with the first string from right to left) and return the resultant string.

```
def interleave(s1: str, s2: str) -> str:
```

I was able to solve this word problem but I need help putting it in a function

```
def interleave(s1: str, s2: str) -> str:
    string1 = s1[::-1]
    string2 = s2[::-1]

    for i in range(len(string1)):
        print(string2[i] + string1[i], end = "")
    
    return print

print(interleave("1234", "5678"))
```

Comment: What's wrong with your code now?  And what's your expected output?  Also these two strings are always same size, what if they are different size?

Comment: What is the purpose of `return print`?

Answer (score 1):

I can't tell from your question what should happen when the strings are unequal in length. My basic solution would be

```
def interleave(str1, str2):
    return ''.join(c1 + c2 for c1, c2 in zip(str1, str2))
```

but this will stop with the shortest of the two input strings.

Comment: Very nice use of *generator expression* .

Answer (score 1):

Right now, the function prints the results.  Instead store the results in a variable, which you return when done.

Like so:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3

def interleave(s1: str, s2: str) -> str:
    string1 = s1[::-1]
    string2 = s2[::-1]
    interleaved_string = ''

    for i in range(len(string1)):
        interleaved_string += string2[i] + string1[i]

    return interleaved_string

print(interleave("1234", "5678"))
```

Answer (score 0):

Your whole loop can be made into a one-liner using `zip` and `map` (or a generator comprehension):

```
def interleave(str1: str, str2: str) -> str:
    # Alternatively, consider itertools.zip_longest
    if len(str1) != len(str2): 
        raise ValueError("Strings must be equal in length.")
    return ''.join(map(''.join, zip(str1[::-1], str2[::-1])))
```

Input:

```
joined_str = interleave("1234", "5678")
print(joined_str)
```

Output:

```
'48372615'
```